# RabbitMQ: What is the default x-message-ttl value

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I couldn't find in RabbitMQ documentation the default x-message-ttl value comes with the installation.

I know how to set it to a desired value but I am curious to know the default value.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are no `x-message-ttl` argument set by default from the broker side, so basically you can interpret default value as infinity.

If you publish message without ttl to queue without ttl set (yupp, there are per-message and per-queue ttl arguments, see note below):

- if message published as persistent and queue declared as persistent message will stay in queue as long as it will not be consumed;
- if message was not published as persistent or queue was not declared as persistent, then message will stay in queue as long as it will not be consumed or until broker restart.

TTL note:

When both per-message and per-queue ttl set broker use the minimal vale. For example, if per-message ttl is 10000 (10 sec) and per-queue ttl is 20000 (20 sec) then per-message ttl will applied.

Per-message TTL note:

Messages with expired ttl will stay in queue as long as they not reached queue head. Don't worry, they will not be send to consumer, but they will take some resources until they reach head. This is how RabbitMQ queues works (they stick to FIFO idea, which is sometimes may break strict compatibility with AMQP protocol). See [Caveats section in Time-To-Live Extensions](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats) for more.

Comment: Messages stay in the queue not until they "reach queue head" but  until they are delivered to a consumer and acknowledged or rejected (without re-queueing). With automatic acknowledgement mode, this means "as soon as they are sent out". AMQP 0-9-1 queues are FIFO but with re-queueing this is not clear how it should work. RabbitMQ tries to preserve the original order of messages.

Comment: When per-message TTL expires, that message will not be removed from queue (it still utilize some resources like memory or disc) until it will not reach the queue head. See rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats for details. And with re-queuing it is also very clear, messages are not removed from queue until they are ack'ed (when auto-ack used they ack'ed automatically on broker side, regardless they are actually consumed by client).