# RabbitMQ: Client does not receive messages sent before client boots

Tags: clojure, jvm, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ with Langohr (the clojure client). I can receive messages fine if the consumer is already running, but if I send messages before the client is booted, the client never receives those messages.

Is there a configuration option (or constellation of configuration options for both server and client) that ensures the client can receive messages generated before it was running?

How do I start trying to test or debug this?

I am using the default exchange. Here is the code I'm using to set up the client:

```clj
(ns sisyphus.rabbit
  (:require
   [cheshire.core :as json]
   [langohr.core :as lcore]
   [langohr.channel :as lchannel]
   [langohr.exchange :as lexchange]
   [langohr.queue :as lqueue]
   [langohr.consumers :as lconsumers]
   [langohr.basic :as lbasic]
   [sisyphus.log :as log]))

(defn connect!
  [config]
  (let [connection (lcore/connect {})
        channel (lchannel/open connection)
        _ (lbasic/qos channel 1)
        queue-name (get config :queue "sisyphus")
        exchange (get config :exchange "")
        queue (lqueue/declare channel "sisyphus" {:exclusive false :durable true})
        routing-key (get config :routing-key "sisyphus")]
    (if-not (= exchange "")
      (lqueue/bind channel queue-name exchange {:routing-key routing-key}))
    {:queue queue
     :queue-name queue-name
     :exchange exchange
     :routing-key routing-key
     :connection connection
     :channel channel
     :config config})
```

Then to publish:

```clj
(defn publish!
  [rabbit message]
  (lbasic/publish
   (:channel rabbit)
   (:exchange rabbit)
   (:routing-key rabbit)
   (json/generate-string message)
   {:content-type "text/plain"
    :peristent true}))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I see that the consumer declares a durable queue and binds it to the exchange. This part of the topology should persist even if the consumer goes away. Is this the case? If yes, messages routed to this queue should sit there until the consumer starts consuming. Does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you need to set `:auto-delete false` to get a durable queue to behave well. The more you know!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can set a time to live on both the messages and the queue. So the queue sticks around when nobody is connected to it, and so the messages are kept for a while without being declared "dead"

http://clojurerabbitmq.info/articles/extensions.html#per-queue-message-time-to-live

> Example
>
> The example below sets the message TTL for a new server-named queue to be 500 milliseconds. It then publishes a message that is routed to the queue and counts messages in the queue after waiting for 600 milliseconds:

```
(ns clojurewerkz.langohr.examples.per-queue-message-ttl
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [langohr.core    :as rmq]
            [langohr.channel :as lch]
            [langohr.queue   :as lq]
            [langohr.basic   :as lb]))

(def ^{:const true}
  default-exchange-name "")

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [conn  (rmq/connect)
        ch    (lch/open conn)
        qname "clojurewerkz.langohr.examples.per-queue-message-ttl"]
    (lq/declare ch qname {:arguments {"x-message-ttl" 500} :durable false})
    (lb/publish ch default-exchange-name qname "a message")
    (Thread/sleep 50)
    (println (format "Queue %s has %d messages" qname (lq/message-count ch qname)))
    (println "Waiting for 600 ms")
    (Thread/sleep 600)
    (println (format "Queue %s has %d messages" qname (lq/message-count ch qname)))
    (println "[main] Disconnecting...")
    (rmq/close ch)
    (rmq/close conn)))
```

Comment: Hmmm based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946181/rabbitmq-what-is-the-default-x-message-ttl-value It looks like the default TTL is infinity, so I don't see how this would help?

Comment: is that the time for messages to live or the time for the queue to continue to exist? Can you confirm that the TTL values are as expected?